# Can't count the total admins

Tags: asp-classic

Everytime I try access my default.asp gives me error

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80040e10'
>
> No value given for one or more required parameters.
>
> /mysite/default.asp, line 65

I have this function according the line 65

```
Function GetTotalAdminsSys
    Set RS = Conn.Execute("SELECT COUNT(id) as UserCount FROM Admins WHERE Role = admin ")
    GetTotalAdminsSys = RS("UserCount")
    RS.Close
End Function
```

Can some one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@petepetey you are missing the ' in admin

should be `Role = 'admin'`

Comment: thanks you are right.. I can't figure how I miss that